# Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs, routes, angular-ui-router, angularjs-routing

I am currently learning AngularJS & Ionic by creating a simple podcast app.
I am trying to use routeParams to get the "itemId" but I am getting the following error:

```js
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParamsProvider <- $routeParams <- DetailsController
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.3/$injector/unpr?p0=%24routeParamsProvider%20%3C-%20%24routeParams%20%3C-%20DetailsController
minErr/
```

Now this is how I pass the "itemId"

```js
  .state('ted', {
    url: '/ted/:itemId',
    templateUrl: 'templates/ted-talks.html',
    controller: 'DetailsController'
  })
```

and here is my controller:

```js
starter.controller("DetailsController", ["$scope", "$routeParams", "$http", function ($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
  $http.get('http://api.npr.org/query?id=57&apiKey={I've taken the ID off})
  .success(function(data, status, headers, config){
    var x2js = new X2JS();
    var jsonOutput = x2js.xml_str2json(data);
    console.log(jsonOutput);

     $scope.stories = jsonOutput.nprml.list.story;
     
     if($routeParams.itemId) {
      console.log('Single page id' + $routeParams.itemId);
     }


  })
  .error(function(data, status, headers, config){
    alert('There is a problem');
  })
}]);
```

Any ideas what causes this error? I belive that the routeParams is already included in the ionic framework as the demos they provide seem to work, bu I can't figure out how.

Any help is much appreceated :)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

As you are using `Angular-ui-router` you should use `$stateParams` dependency  instead of `$routeParams` which are meant to use for `ui-router`(Angular ui-router `$stateProvider`)

```
if($stateParams.itemId) {
    console.log('Single page id' + $stateParams.itemId);
}
```

> `$routeParams` is available there for `ngRoute` module(AngularJS
>   routing `$routerProvider`)

Comment: You have no idea how long I've been banging my head over that. Thanks so much! 
Was trying to pass params into my controller and nothing was working haha....

Comment: @dannio Pleased to know that I helped. Thanks :)